# How do I read these coordinates from a spreadsheet?

Tags: java, spreadsheet

Okay so I have a spreadsheet of x, y, and z coordinates. The x and y are integers, and the z is a float. I want to read all of the coordinates, but I'm getting an error when I try to run it. This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "XCoord"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source
```

And here is my code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./data/graphXYZ.csv"));
    String dataRow = br.readLine(); // Read first line.

    // The while checks to see if the data is null. If 
    // it is, we've hit the end of the file. If not, 
    // process the data.
    int i = 0;
    int xCoord, yCoord;
    float zCoord;

    while (dataRow != null) {
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        xCoord = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[0]);
        yCoord = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[1]);
        zCoord = Float.parseFloat(dataArray[2]);
        for(String item:dataArray) {
            System.out.print(xCoord + "\t");
            System.out.print(yCoord + "\t");
            System.out.print(zCoord + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
        dataRow = br.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
    }
```

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Comment: Skip the first line, since it is "headers" for the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right there in the exception that is thrown. As esej says in the comments, you are parsing a first row of column names (as opposed to numbers). Hence the NumberFormatException for input string "XCoord"

The solution is to skip the first row, or remove it from the data file.

Comment: Yep. The way to do this is by adding a `br.readLine()` right after the instantiation (and not storing it to a variable).